# iam creating a project education details

Tags: input, types

Iam creating a project  education details if a person fills his tenth passed out year the in the next input type it asks for 12th intermediate  and after engineering so by based on 10th passed out it should add +2 for intermediate or greater than 2 if a person enter the passed out year less than 2 of 12th then its should show the text as enter the correct passed year and same it should repeat to engineering passed out year but it should add 4 years after 12 intermediate or more than 4 how can we do this

Comment: Get the value of said input's and calculate, base 10 is pretty easy to work with. What are you stuck on?

Comment: do you want suggestion on how to achieve or with which technology?

Comment: if there is an input type box of 10th I entered 2013 and after it asks for 12th i will enter 2014 then it should not accept that because in 1 year year you cannot complete your 12 so it should accept if i enter 2015 or more than that

Comment: just i need the logic how to write

Answer (score 0):

You can set min accept value for 12th passing year field, you have to call on change event on 10th passing year field and after adding 2 years to that value you have to set it for 12th year min passing year

```
document.getElementById("tenthPassingYear").onchange = function () {
    var twelvethPassingYear = document.getElementById("twelvethPassingYear");

    //Set min value of 12th passing year
    twelvethPassingYear.setAttribute("min", this.value + 2);
}
```

Comment: your welcome @medicopractolytics, if this works for you, then upvote or accept this as correct answer

Comment: yah  surely i will do that